# Make discord.py bot say something in a specific channel when the command is sent from a different server

Tags: python

Basically, I have a developer console server that's seperate from the server that I'm trying to make the bot say something in. My goal is to have a command that says whatever I want it to say in a specific server and channel (using the server in channel id's) based on a prompt that I give from a different server.

```
async def Say(ctx, *, message):
        target_guild = bot.get_guild(the guild id)
        target_channel = target_guild.get_channel(the channel id)

        await target_channel.send(message)
```

this is the code that I'm trying to use, but whenever I try to use it, nothing happens. No error message, but no output either. I have confirmed that the TOKEN is correct and both IDs are also correct. How do I make this a functioning command?

Answer (score 0):

Discord uses a different ID for every channel so `target_guild = bot.get_guild(the guild id)` is not needed. Try this:

```py
async def Say(ctx, *, message):
    target_channel = bot.get_channel(channel_id) # Make sure to replace channel_id with an integer and not a string
    await target_channel.send(message)
```